# How to "align" 2 strings?

Tags: php, objective-c, string, algorithm, alignment

First let me explain what I mean by "alignment".

Let's say we have to strings : e.g. AGBCDEF  ABCDIEFK

Their "alignment" would be :

```
A - G - B - C - D -   - E - F -
A -   - B - C - D - I - E - F - K
-----------------------------------

A - ? - B - C - D - ? - E - F - ?
```

Another (quite simplified) example (since I believe my question has probably something to do with NLP) :

```
I give Mary a kiss
I give Ann a book
----------------------
I give X a Y
```

How would you go about that? Any ideas (or even reference) regarding the algorithm?

I'm probably going to write this in Objective-C (or PHP), but any code would be welcome.

Comment: I've read your question like five time and still have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I think he wants an inline diff.

Comment: @blockhead I think my question is part of Natural Language Processing theory; though I'm not sure how it could be classified.

Comment: The Stanford NLP course (it's free) has a set of slides on this topic. Sign up for it and look through the slides.

Comment: @MarkByers Just added another example of what I need (though it's not the use I have in mind; but you'll definitely get an idea...)

Comment: I don't see the pattern. One string needs to have more priority over the other, otherwise the result could be random.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Actually, you're quite right; or you could end up with a number of different "alignments".

Comment: The first one just looks like set intersection; the second isn't enough data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [longest common subsequence.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

Comment: Great answer! I've already written an Objective-C implementation of the algorithm (I'll post it later...)

Comment: (hint: it's not 100% the answer... but the WAY to the answer)

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is something like minimum edit distance from natural language processing. Look at a demo of the Levenshtein distance algorithm [here](http://www.let.rug.nl/kleiweg/lev/)

Comment: I think this (or @kilotaras's answer) is quite possibly what I need... Thanks a lot! I'm having a look into it...