# Multiple Sequence Alignment (Longest Common Subsequence)?

Tags: python, objective-c, perl, lcs, sequence-alignment

OK this is what I want to do:

Get more than two strings and "align" them (no DNA/RNA sequence or the like, just regular strings with not like 1000 items in each of them)

I've already done some work with pairwise alignment (align two strings) however the "gaps" create some issues for me when trying to align more than one pair.

**Example *(one I'm currently testing)*:**

```
ABCDEF
ABGHCEEF
AJKLBCDYEOF

AB--CDEF
ABGHCEEF
=======================
AB--C-EF

A-B--C--E-F
AJKLBCDYEOF
=======================
A----C--E-F
```

**And another (more illustrative) example :**

```
http://nest.drkameleon.com
http://www.google.com
http://www.yahoo.com

http://nest.drkameleon.com
http://-www.--google--.com

=======================
http://----.------le--.com

http://----.------le--.com
http://-www.-----yahoo.com

=======================
http://----.----------.com
```

**What I'm currently doing :**

- Sort the strings (longer strings come first in the list)
- Align the first pair : A-B and get the result (let's say `R1`)
- Then align the second pair : `R1` and `C` (result in `R2`)
- Then align the third pair    : `R2` and `D`
- And so on...

So what's in your mind? How could I go for that? Is there a better way? (Of course, there must be...)

I'd rather do that in Perl/Python or something along these lines, however any type of code/reference would be more than welcome! :-)

Comment: Can you perhaps post some examples of what the inputs and outputs might be? I'm not 100% on what you actually want to do.

Comment: also take a look at this article which explains in a detailed way the LCS problem in python. http://wordaligned.org/articles/longest-common-subsequence#toc21

Comment: @Li-aungYip Here's what I mean : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065293/how-to-align-2-strings

Comment: @luke14free This is correct; although, it deals only with pair-wise alignment. What I need is a way to align MORE than 2 string sequences...

Comment: I suggest you give us some sample groups to work with, so we have an idea of how the string differ and how they are similar.

Comment: @PhilH I've update my main post; please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be able to cast this problem as a more general string *diff* problem instead of a string *alignment*. Consider how GNU `diff` is used for finding differences between two files, and use the same algorithms as are used to perform an N-way `diff`.

I'm not sure if the time/memory complexity of this approach is amenable to your needs, but you can at least think about the problem this way.

Answer (score 1):

There is an algorithm based on Levenshtein algorithm to compute the longest common sequence, with optional spaces. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Well, obviously I have played a lot with the Levenshtein algorithm, and then gave a try even to Hirschberg's, but what may come closer to my case is the **Needleman-Wunsch Algorithm** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm)